# How to alter the column datatype of the managed delta table using pyspark?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks

How to alter the column datatype based on the input parameter using pyspark

```
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType,BooleanType,DateType
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
Column_Name="EFFECTIVE_DATE"
df=spark.sql(f"select * from TableA")
df.withColumn({Column_Name},col({Column_Name}).cast(DateType())
```

Comment: from where this input comes? widgets? or something else?

Comment: datafactory input parameter

Answer (score 0):

input come always through widget:

```
input = dbutils.widgets.get("X")
```

so assume that:

```
input == "int"
```

then instead of using IntegerType() function you can just use string "int" type as cast so:

```
df.withColumn({Column_Name},col({Column_Name}).cast(input)
```